# JsonPath assertions type JSONArray

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, jsonpath, mockmvc

I'm trying to make a test validating one json using JsonPath, I could create the test, but when I validate what I got is probably a type error `Expected: <[4]> but: was <[4]>` my test is this:

```
mockmvc.perform(get("/client/rating"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(3)))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[?(@.id == prod1)].rate", equalTo(new JSONArray("[4]"))));
```

I don't have the Json tested here, but the value is right, the only problem is its type...

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this test this way:

```
mockmvc.perform(get("/client/rating"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(3)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[?(@.id == prod1)].rate").value(4));
```